# How do I make class/struct types colorize?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this in my visual studio code:

[image]

And I want it to be like in visual studio 17:

[image]

ShaderProgram, Camera and StaticBatch are sturcts/classes.

Answer (score -1):

First suggestion. If you are a student, go to [JetBrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/), sign up for a free license, and install Resharper. I don't think we're supposed to advertise in answers. But I promise, your VS experience will be 100 times better.

Second, if VS 2017 menus are similar to VS 2015, you just need to go to Tools -> OPtions -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors and select "Text Editor" from the drop down.

Comment: This question is about [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), not Visual Studio.

Comment: Correct. And I deserve the down vote for missing that. :P